# DateTime2 conversion randomly removes space between date and time

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a small console application which is to import a CSV file into a database. It is in .NET CORE 3.1. The CSV file gets imported without any issues. The issue arises with trying to save the data to the table. The error being received is "String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated." This is received during the `context.SaveChanges()` call. To determine exactly what the error is, loaded up Profiler to see the offending statement. The offending piece of code was related to a field that holds a date and time. To start from the beginning and lead up to the issue.

The imported data is in a column and is represented as follows:

```
"20200404121655500" 
"20200404121755500"
```

The import model property is defined as follows:

```
public string Date_And_Time { get; set; }
```

The data model property is defined as follows:

```
[Column(TypeName = "DATETIME2(7)")]
public DateTime? Date_And_Time { get; set; }
```

The conversion used to get the imported string to the data model field is as follows:

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(Date_And_Time.Trim()
.PadRight(21, '0')
.Substring(0, 21), "yyyyMMddHHmmssFFFFFFF", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime newDateTime)) 
{ model.Date_And_Time = newDateTime; }
else { model.Date_And_Time = null; }
```

While debugging when the 2 different dates are processed then are set in the `model.Date_And_Time` as expected. The object expands producing all the correct information (year, day, hour, etc.). Prior to executing `SaveChanges`, inspecting the objects shows they both have correct `DateTime` objects. However upon executing that command throws the above SQL exception. When inspecting the merge command created by EF the dates are differently formatted. They are as follows:

```
'2020-04-0412:16:55.5000000' and '2020-04-04 12:17:55.5000000'
```

The first does not have a space between the date and time where as the second has a space. The first is what is causing the exception. When doing the `SaveChanges` there are on average 20 records being saved and some have the space and some do not there is no pattern that I can find. I have tried using the exact same date time and that also has some with and some without space.

Comment: I didn't find any issue. I just copy-pasted your code, and the data was inserted without any exception. `2020-04-04 12:17:55.5000000` - this is your first DateTime? value in my database.

Comment: Firstly, EF Core doesn't generate `MERGE` statements. Secondly, you haven't shown the generated SQL. My guess is that you have a third-party library, or are manually building up the SQL, and that this is not an EF problem.

Comment: I would expect EF to generate a properly parameterized query with a datetime2 SqlType but it looks like the value may be being passed as a string literal. Also, I would expect a different error with a malformed datetime value ("Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string") rather than a truncation error. It seems there are some puzzle pieces missing in your question. Maybe providing the full text from Profiler will provide some clues.

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and errors I switched from DateTime to DateTimeOffset. This was done on the property of the data model propriety, the type attribute of the same property and the TryParseException. No other changes and it ran with no exceptions. Needed to do another migration due to the change in attribute causing the table field tire change.

The only 3rd party package used was to import the CSV for and that went successfully.

The parametrized merge statement was seen in the profiler sorry I didn't City it better finding the answer.

I have no idea why the model with a C# data type of DateTime would produce a string although the parameter itself was designated as DateTime2 the value being passed in was in string format.

I don't understand what the difference is between the 2 data types and how they are handled that would cause this issue. I appreciate the comments and attempting to help.